"No root file system is defined" but with additional error of EPI
"No root file system is defined" shows up when Ubuntu installation. Other solutions were to select an option other than EPI but that show another error

Do you mean UEFI/EFI? And if Something Else install option you have to select or create a partition and change/edit it to be / (root). Some installers like Calamares with some Flavors may want you to specify which is ESP - efi system partition. Otherwise Ubuntu defaults to ESP on first drive.
